# iPhone call and data services stop working until toggling flight mode

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 12 Pro that is only about a year old. It stops receiving texts and calls and I'm unable to use data services until I toggle flight mode on and off. These services then function for a very short period of time (sometimes less than a minute) before I have to do it again.

I've tried resetting all network settings and I've changed my sim card.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Is there any way to debug further?